How can discrete wavelet transform (DWT) help in data reduction
Hi I am reading Data Mining concepts and Techniques by jiawei Han. In page 100 it is mentioned that Wavelet transform helps in data reduction. But I can not find the mathematical proof of this as well as I dont see it is relevant. Please help me explain about it

